# AngularJs dropdown with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, firebase

I'm trying to create a dropdown list from an angular controller:
My html code:

```
  <select>
  <option value="" disabled selected >Choose your option</option>
  <option ng-repeat="ty in type">{{ty.$value}}</option>
  </select>
```

Controller code:

```
var typeRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "/type");
var typeArray = $firebase(typeRef).$asArray();
typeArray.$loaded().then( function (data) {
            $scope.type = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
```

In this case it works:

```
<ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content'>
<li ng-repeat="ty in type"><a href="#!">{{ty.$value}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `ty.$value` works in above code, but in this `<select>` tag doesn't show anything any idea why is that?

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: added in the question

Comment: You should not nest `option` tags inside `option`! so use `ng-repeat` in the `select` tag!

Comment: @Bellash I want to have multiple choices in one dropdown, if I do what you said I will have multiples dropdowns

Comment: You don't need `$loaded()`: `$scope.type = $firebase(typeRef).$asArray()`. And please don't use `console.log` to debug the AngularFire loading sequence. Just put `<pre>{{ type | json }}</pre>` in your HTML. The docs are great too: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro (especially if you upgrade to the latest version).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `{
  "$value": "bestEmployee",
  "$id": "Best Employee",
  "$priority": null
}` this is first object of my array printed with `<pre>{{ type | json }}</pre>`, I also changed the controller eliminating `$loaded()` but still dropdown is not populated

Comment: I think I found the problem, `materialize.css` would not alowed the dropdown to show the list , I added`<select class="browser-default">` and now the data is showing in the dropdown

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tr2uL76L/1/ you can see here, if you remove the browser-default class the dropdown will not show the data

Comment: Cool. Please write it up as an answer, so that you can accept it and claim the associated fame/upvotes.. :-)

Comment: I'm happy with finding the problem, don't need the fame, thanks a lot for all your advice

Comment: Uuuupgraaaaade. $asArray() is many versions behind and was deprecated probably 6 months ago.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `ng-repeat`, you can use `ng-options`

```
<select ng-options="ty.$value for ty in type" ng-model="something">
<select>
```

Comment: `<select ng-options="ty.$value for ty in type" ng-model="achvtype">
                      <option value="" disabled selected >Choose your option</option>
                    </select>` this code won't work, no errors in console, and the `type` array i correct

Comment: @AndreiMaieras, can you post a broken jsbin?  Here is a working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/povaqimuca/edit?html,js,output

Comment: `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` add this css to yours and you have the broken jsbin

Comment: I use materialize.css for styling and for some reason, it stops the listing of the elements brought in from the controller

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tr2uL76L/1/ you can see here, if you remove the browser-default class the dropdown will not show the data

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<select ng-options="ty.$value as ty.$value for ty in type" ng-model="achvtype"> <option value="" disabled selected >Choose your option</option> </select>
```

http://jsbin.com/juhamul/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This looks great, but from some reason still no item in my dropdown, I'm lost.

Comment: How is possible that my object printed in the console looks exactly the same with yours, but no item in the dropdown, can a HTML element interfere in this??

Comment: can you make changes in jsbin? also give a sample array

Comment: `0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:28"
$id: "Finance"
$priority: null
$value: "finance"
__proto__: Object` This is 1 element from the array, I'll try to change the jsbin, thanks a lot